# Accessing view via controller in episerver CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, episerver

I have a MVC controller inside my .NET project which is a little bit modified version of standard MVC controller since I'm using the Episerver CMS. The code for controller is as following:

```
 public class StartPageController : PageController<StartPage>
    {
        // GET: StartPage
        public ActionResult Index(StartPage currentPage)
        {

            return View(currentPage);
        }
    }
```

And now when I try to access the view via controller like following:

```
http://localhost:port/TestPage
```

This should (with the regular MVC controller) return the Index.cshtml view that I created, but it doesn't ... The error that I'm getting is:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

How can I setup the controller now so that I can access the view via controller... ?

Best regards

Comment: Where is your view stored, and what is it called?

Comment: Have you created the page instance via episerver admin?

Answer (score 3):

If you are serving CMS page and do have a page controller behind the scene, you have to access url with name of the CMS page ("Name in URL" property of the page). That's the value EPiServer will look for when trying to "route" your request to corresponding page controller.

So theoretically you might have page controller named `ThisIsMyPageController : PageController<StartPage>` and name of the page is "Hello". Then you would need to hit "http://localhost/hello" and EPiServer will make sure that request to "/hello" is routed to your page controller.

Another note. is if this is `StartPage` and supposed to be as root page for your side, and if EPiServer site is setup correctly - you should just access "http://localhost" and EPiServer should call your page type controller to handle request to site's root page.